# What happened to the armv7l build of LEDE?

Tags: arm, router, lede

`uname -a` shows,

```
Linux LEDE 4.4.71 #0 SMP Wed Jun 7 19:24:41 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

But I don't see an [`armv7` even available on the build targets for 17.01.4](https://downloads.lede-project.org/releases/17.01.4/targets/). It's the same major and minor build number.

Is `armv7` the `ar71xx` build?

I'm running a **"Netgear Nighthawk X4S R7800"**.

LuCI shows

> LEDE Reboot 17.01.2 r3435-65eec8bd5f / LuCI lede-17.01 branch (git-17.152.82987-7f6fc16)

Answer (score 2):

[The device page for the "Netgear Nighthawk X4S R7800"](https://lede-project.org/toh/hwdata/netgear/netgear_r7800) lists it as

```
Target: ipq806x
```

So it's neither `armv7`, nor `ar71xx`. The CPU inside is Qualcomm Atheros **IPQ8065**CPU.

Alternatively you can check [`/etc/openwrt_release`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400213/3285)