# How do I find out the build version to download with LEDE?

Tags: command-line, router, system-information, lede

Following on the footsteps of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400207/3285), which I was able to figure out with the [device page](https://lede-project.org/toh/hwdata/netgear/netgear_r7800) for my device. I want to know if it is possible to find out he build information *without* using the web interface?

Such as with an administration/cli tool.

Answer (score 3):

That information can be found in `/etc/openwrt_release` under `DISTRIB_TARGET`

```
DISTRIB_ID='LEDE'
DISTRIB_RELEASE='17.01.2'
DISTRIB_REVISION='r3435-65eec8bd5f'
DISTRIB_CODENAME='reboot'
DISTRIB_TARGET='ipq806x/generic'
DISTRIB_ARCH='arm_cortex-a15_neon-vfpv4'
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION='LEDE Reboot 17.01.2 r3435-65eec8bd5f'
DISTRIB_TAINTS='no-all'
```

Or as `LEDE_BOARD` in `/etc/os-release`

```
NAME="LEDE"
VERSION="17.01.2, Reboot"
ID="lede"
ID_LIKE="lede openwrt"
PRETTY_NAME="LEDE Reboot 17.01.2"
VERSION_ID="17.01.2"
HOME_URL="http://lede-project.org/"
BUG_URL="http://bugs.lede-project.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://forum.lede-project.org/"
BUILD_ID="r3435-65eec8bd5f"
LEDE_BOARD="ipq806x/generic"
LEDE_ARCH="arm_cortex-a15_neon-vfpv4"
LEDE_TAINTS="no-all"
LEDE_DEVICE_MANUFACTURER="LEDE"
LEDE_DEVICE_MANUFACTURER_URL="http://lede-project.org/"
LEDE_DEVICE_PRODUCT="Generic"
LEDE_DEVICE_REVISION="v0"
LEDE_RELEASE="LEDE Reboot 17.01.2 r3435-65eec8bd5f"
```